# Trying to change permissions using ksh script

Tags: concatenation, asterisk, ksh

I am new to ksh and am trying to change multiple file permissions using a ksh script, but I am unable to concatenate an asterisk in my script.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 for i in `cat /gpfs_cache/open/srcfile.csv`
 do
    echo "Changing permissions in $i"
    chmod 0444 ${i}"*"
 done
```

srcfile.csv contains

`/gpfs_data/open/files/test1/`

`/gpfs_data/open/files/test2/`

The output I get is

```
Changing permissions in /gpfs_data/open/files/test1/
chmod: cannot access `/gpfs_data/open/files/test1/\r*': No such file or  directory
Changing permissions in /gpfs_data/open/files/test2/
chmod: cannot access `/gpfs_data/open/files/test2/\r*': No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote the asterisks.  That causes them to be interpreted literally.

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in `cat /gpfs_cache/open/srcfile.csv`
do
    echo "Changing permissions in $i"
    chmod 0444 ${i}*
done
```

works for me.